# How to prepare sparse data for building autoencoder in TF?

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoder

I have user-item-rating tuples. The users and items are currently both strings (either hash codes or plain text strings, think book or movie titles). The ratings are integers. I'm trying to figure out the data transformation needed to get these ratings into TF to build an autoencoder.

Let's say I have 100K possible items. My thought is that I should feed the model sparse tensors, where each mini-batch would be a set of user-item ratings. Do I need to transform the item strings into integer id's in order to do this? Other than that are there any other details I should know?